# How to prevent the load of a named view using ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two siblings named views and I what to change only the content of one view and keep the other one unchanged.

I am building an application which I have a *not logged* header with **Log in** link and a *logged* header with the **Log out** link.

I have the following code:

index.html

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
```

In my app config I set the following.

This is my initial state:

```
.state("sgi", {
        url: "/home",
        views: {
            'header': {
                templateUrl: 'views/main/header.html'
            },
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'views/main/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            }
        }
    })
```

Then, in my header I have a link for the Login template which is the state set bellow:

```
.state("sgi.login", {
        url: "/login",
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'views/main/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            }
        }
    })
```

In this case, the only view changed is the **content view**. The **header view** is kept as it was.

Also, In the header template I have an **About** link which use the content view.

```
        .state("sgi.about", {
        url: "/sobre",
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'views/main/about.html',
                controller: 'aboutController'
            }
        }
    })
```

Then, after logged I have an state that loads a different template in **content view** and in **header view**. In this header view I have a link to Log out and also the same link to About which use the same state **sgi.about**. 
In both Header for Not Logged and the Header for logged I have the link:

```
<a ui-sref="sgi.about">About</a>
```

My problem is when I am on logged state with the LoggedHeader template and I click on *About* I would like to only change the content view. But what happens is that both view is changed.

How can I change only the content view, and keep unchanged the header view when call the sgi.about state?

Comment: I make a directive for my headers and keep the views for page content. If I want the header to change based on logged in or out or change depending on what view I'm looking at then I use isolate scope.

Comment: I've just checked it out on this [link](http://gon.to/2013/03/23/the-right-way-of-coding-angularjs-how-to-organize-a-regular-webapp/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. UI-router allows one branch of states at a time. This means when you in `sgi.about` it can't keep in mind that you have `login` or `loggedin` in background. You have to implement it on your own specifying multiple nested `about` that have same specification.

```
var aboutState = {
    url: "/sobre",
    views: {
        'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/main/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        }
    };
....
.state("sgi.login.about", aboutState)
.state("sgi.loggedin.about", aboutState);
```

And in header template you use a relative state in `ui-sref=".about"`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a header directive that I use:

First the directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myHeader', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '',
        scope: {user: '=', location: '='},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        }
    };

});
```

Html:

```
<div class="my-header">
    <p>
    {{::user.username}} <a href="#" Ng-show="user">log out</a> <a href="#" ng-show="!user">log in</a><br>
    {{::location}}
    </p>
</div>
```

In the view html it will look like:

```
<my-header user="$root.currentUser" location="location"></my-header>
```

I would place this inside of each view that I want to include the header. In that view's controller I would use:

```
Angular.module('app').controller('AboutController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.location = 'About';
}]);
```

This is a very simple example of course, but you can see how this would allow you to change the logic that goes into the header. You could use this to display different links, different colors, whatever you want based both on location and if the user is logged in or out. You can of course add in your own variables to determine other factors.